# How to expand/length matplotlib plots to cover a wider axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting time series data across several years/decades. Each week lists a number of events, e.g. `02-07-2005 1858`, `02-14-2005 1655`, etc.

At the moment, it is just pandas `Series` data structure.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

df.plot()
```

If I plot between years 2005 and 2006, I get a plot that looks something like this

[image: Events per week, each week from 2005 to 2006]

However, if I begin to plot my entire time series over several years, this data is "compressed" to fit into the same-sized plot.

[image: Events per week, each week from 1988 to 2008]

I would prefer to output an "uncompressed" plot the length of my screen. Is it possible to output "longer" plots with matplotlib?

Comment: Change your `figsize` when you create the figure object and make it wider, such as adding a `f = plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))` line.

Comment: You can also adjust the figure size via the `set_size_inches` method on the figure object.  If you are doing this interactively you can also just resize the window (or plot area in `%matplotlib notebook`).